# Where to find Kevin Borden's WEB structure viewer web-view and Texbraces from David Ness?

Tags: web

Does anybody know how to get these programs / source codes?

At TeXbraces, I'm referring to [Diagnosing TeX Errors with a  Preprocessor](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29ness.pdf)

Comment: I think you're referring to [this article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb13-3/childs.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, I am. But I can't find anything useful about it on the internet. WEB is a bad keyword. It produces a lot of noise. Is it part of spider?